# ¿Cómo convertir video URL a Blob URL con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video, blob

Quiero convertir la url de un video que no está en mi servidor a una url blob, sé que es posible pero los tutoriales y los ejemplos que hay en internet no me sirven, intenté hacerlo con `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest`  pero tampoco me sirve.

la razón por la quiero convertir no importa, solo lo quiero convertir a una url blob y ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si lo que quieres es convertir el url en un blob url, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```js
const url = "https://www.miwebsite.com/algun_url";
const blob = new Blob([url], { type: "text/plain" });
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```